# Return a json-encoded, non-recursive object in FOSRestBundle

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am building a REST API with FOSRestBundle.
My entities have quite a bit of OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional relationships.
Whenever I want to `GET` some entity with the JSON format, *e.g.* `web/app_dev.php/users/1.json` I'm getting a much bigger object than I actually need: all related objects are recursively included. My controllers return the object and have the `@View` annotations.

How can I return an object that just reflects the database row (*i.e.* with only the ids of me related objects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with annotation (http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations : see Groups, Expose/Exclude, or MaxDepth)

I prefer to use the Groups annotation (i have exactly what i want !)

For example :

In the Entity class :

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @JMS\Groups({"main"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="DocumentUnique", inversedBy="Evaluations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="documentUniqueId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @JMS\Groups({"show", "all"}) 
 */
protected $DocumentUnique;    

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=20)
 * @JMS\Groups({"main","all"}) 
 */
 private $title;
```

In the Controller :

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"main"})
 */    
public function cgetAction()
{
    return $this->getRepository('MyEntity')->findAll();
}
```

In you want to expose the id of one relation, you can use the VirtualProperty annotation :

```
/**
 * @JMS\VirtualProperty
 * @JMS\SerializedName("documentUniqueId")
 * @JMS\Groups("main") 
 */    
public function getDocumentUniqueId() {
    if (!$this->DocumentUnique) return null;
    return $this->DocumentUnique->getId();
}
```